# javascript validation with regex breaking all javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing javascript to validate a business calculator / orderform
another team mate has written the math code, but when I put in  my code the whole thing stops.
I can't find my error (I'm more a css/html person)
help?

```
//Order Detail Variables//
var clientname =document.getElementById(clientname);
var phonenumber =document.getElementById(phoneno);
var deliveryaddress=document.getElementById(deliveryaddress);
var suburb =document.getElementById(suburb);
var postcode =document.getElementById(postcode);
var state =document.getElementById(state);
var deliverydistance = document.getElementById(deldistance);
var bagsordered =document.getElementById(bagsordered);
var orderdetailsarray = new Array();

//validation//
// these are boolean variables that when made true// 
//by the validation will allow the calculation and logging to occur//
var clientnamevalid = new Boolean(false);

//Regex Variables//
//these are the regex patterns that are used to //
//confirm that the data is valid//
var alpha = pattern=/^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/;

function validation()
    {
    function validation();

        {console.log (clientname);
        if(alpha.test(clientname));

        var clientnamevalid = true;
            if { clientnamevalid = true; 
                alert(client name valid); //to be replaced with inline alert
        }
            else {

                alert("client name invalid"); 
        }
    }
```

Edit Updated code:

the vars are now

`var clientname =document.getElementById('clientname');`

the function:

```
function validation()

        {console.log (clientname);
        var clientnamevalid = alpha.test(clientname);
        if(clientnamevalid);
        {
            alert('client name valid')  
        }
        else 
        {   
        alert("client name invalid");        
        }
    }
```

Edit Updated code 2:

```
<button name="calculate" id="calcbutton" onclick="validate()"> Calculate </button>

function validate()



{console.log (clientname);
    var clientnamevalid = alpha.test(clientname);
    if(clientnamevalid);
    {
        alert('client name valid'); 
    }
    else 
    {   
    alert("client name invalid");        
    }
    if clientnamevalid = true;
    {   
        function calculateorder();
    }
}
```

edit 3:

```
function validate()

        {console.log (clientname);
        var clientnamevalid = alpha.test(clientname);
        if(clientnamevalid);
        {
            alert("client name valid"); //edited from single quotations
        }
        else 
        {   
        alert("client name invalid");        
        }
        if (clientnamevalid == true);
        {   
            calculateorder();
        }
        else
        {
        alert ("please review form");
        }
    }
```

calc order func:

```
function calculateorder()
    {
            orderdetailsarray [0] = document.forms["orderform1"] ["clientname"].value; 
            orderdetailsarray [1] = document.forms["orderform1"] ["phoneno"].value ;
            orderdetailsarray [2] = document.forms["orderform1"] ["deliveryaddress"].value;
            orderdetailsarray [3] = document.forms["orderform1"] ["suburb"].value;
            orderdetailsarray [4] = document.forms["orderform1"] ["postcode"].value;    
            orderdetailsarray [6] = parseFloat(document.forms["orderform1"] ["deldistance"].value);
            orderdetailsarray [7] = parseFloat(document.forms["orderform1"] ["bagsordered"].value);
            orderdetailsarray [8] = document.forms["orderform1"] ["orderdate"].value;

        //gross calculation 
        var grossbagcost = orderdetailsarray[7] * millendcost;
        grossbagcost = Math.round(grossbagcost *100)/100;
        document.forms["resultsform"] ["bagsgross"].value = grossbagcost;
        //end gross calculation

        //discount amount calculation
        if (orderdetailsarray [7] <=50)

        {
            var discountedbagcost = grossbagcost * discountnil;
            document.forms["resultsform"] ["discount"].value = discountedbagcost;
        }

        else if (orderdetailsarray[7] >50 && orderdetailsarray[7] <100)

        {
            var discountedbagcost = grossbagcost * discount4percent;
            discountedbagcost = Math.round(discountedbagcost *100)/100;
            document.forms["resultsform"] ["discount"].value = discountedbagcost;

        }

        else if (orderdetailsarray[7] >=100)

        {
            var discountedbagcost = grossbagcost * discount7percent;
            discountedbagcost = Math.round(discountedbagcost *100)/100;
            document.forms["resultsform"] ["discount"].value = discountedbagcost;

        }
```

updated code with null check

```
function validate()

    {console.log (clientname);

        //pattern test

        var clientnamevalid == alpha.test(clientname);
        if(clientnamevalid);
        {
            alert("client name valid");
        }
        else 
        {   
            alert("client name invalid");   

        //null check    

        }   
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Client name cannot be left blank");
                clientnamenotnull == false;
        }
        else
        { 
            clientnamenotnull == true;
        }

        //is the whole form valid

    {
        if (clientnamevalid == true)
        if (clientnamenotnull) == true)
        {   
            calculateorder();
        }
        else
        {
        alert ("please review form");
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks :) there still seems to be a problem though

Comment: urg, I almost want to repost the question, its late and I'm desperate for answers

Comment: its getting uncomfortably close to 4am and I have to be up early will check in tomorrow thanks everyone for your help, I would give you all upvotes if I could. @elior

Comment: see my edit, if the user name is empty, it needs to alert that the name can't be empty, else it should to the functionality.. but there must be a form that the user can fill his details.. I hope this is help

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be problem area:

```
function validation()
    {
    function validation();
```

You have function inside another function.

Answer (score 1):

Your function *validation()* is one big bug.
Did you mean

```
function validation(clientname)
{
    console.log (clientname);
    var clientnamevalid = alpha.test(clientname);
    if (clientnamevalid)
    {
        alert('client name valid');
    }
    else
    {
        alert("client name invalid"); 
    }
}
```

And you don't call that function in your code. And remember, parentheses and curly braces position does matter.

Comment: the function validates several text boxes. So i'm not sure how much of a bug it is.

Comment: @hollowpetal Whatever its intended purpose, it is definitely very buggy.

Comment: I mean the `validation(clientname)` I presume if I then added other parts to validate (as declared) that would cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Another one, adding to anubhava's answer you need to change all getElementById from

```
document.getElementById(deldistance);
```

to

```
document.getElementById('deldistance');
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to anubhava and Surender, 
the `document.getElementById()` get string.. so you need to change all this

```
//Order Detail Variables//
var clientname =document.getElementById(clientname);
var phonenumber =document.getElementById(phoneno);
var deliveryaddress=document.getElementById(deliveryaddress);
var suburb =document.getElementById(suburb);
var postcode =document.getElementById(postcode);
var state =document.getElementById(state);
var deliverydistance = document.getElementById(deldistance);
var bagsordered =document.getElementById(bagsordered);
```

and write the parameters between quotes.

for example:

```
var bagsordered = document.getElementById('bagsordered');
```

because as you wrote it, it confuse the compiler. 
you can't pass the variable you just declare now at the same line you want his id.

if you're a css/html person as you say, you know that when you create an html button or div
you can define his id.

like `<input type="button" id="order" value="press to order" />`

now in javascript you can add functionality to this button. so when you want to get
this button in javaScript you can use the function `document.getElementById('order')`

see? I gave the id of the button that was declared in the html code.

hope you understand what i mean

**Edit**

look, when you have a button, as you said. for example i'll use the button I wrote before.

```
<input type ="button" id="order" value="press to order"/>
```

now if I have a function called "function()"; 
and I want that when the user will press on the button the function will be called 
so I'll add to the html code of the button the onclick

so now it will be :

```
<input type = "button" id="order" value ="press to order" onclick="function()"/>
```

now when the user will click on that button, the function will be called and the code in it will performed

in addition, when you write a function that will change some label or button text. 
you will need to get theirs id. 
if my function is "changeText()". and I have a button with value "Hello" and id = "btn"
and I want to change the button value's from "Hello" to "wow" 
so I need to get that button right?

and how do I get it? 
with the method `document.getElementById`

here is the code:

```
function changeText()
{
   var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
   btn.value = "wow";
}
```

**Edit 2:** 
clientnamevalid is boolean,right?

so when you want to check if it true or false, you can use the if statement.

```
if (clientnamevalid == true)
{  
    // do something, like call to calculateorder
    calculateorder();
} 
else // it's false
{
     // do something else
}
```

note that you don't have to compare the 'clientnamevalid' variable or all another boolean variable to 'true' or 'false', the if statement does it alone. so you can write

```
if (clientnamevalid) // means that the clientnamevalid is true
{
     calculateorder(); 
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

**Edit 3:**
**  From where you get the client name?! you need to enable the user to enter his name.. 
  So you need a Form.. **

```
function validate()
{   
    console.log (clientname);

    if (clientname != ""  || clientname != null)
    {
         var clientnamevalid = alpha.test(clientname);
         if(clientnamevalid)
         {
             alert("client name valid");
             calculateorder();
         } 
         else 
         {   
             alert("client name invalid, please review form");
         }
   }
   else
   {
        alert("client name can't be empty!");
   }
}
```

Comment: my button is `<button name="calculate" id="calcbutton" onclick="calculateorder()"> Calculate </button>` 

where and how do I apply the `document.getElementById('calcbutton')` code or is the onclick that the other dev left for their stuff enough?

Comment: Quotes is not the only thing. A `.value` is also missing. I also fail to see the reason for `new Boolean(false)`. It is almost always a mistake to do this instead of just using `false`.

Comment: @IngoBürk is the `new Boolean(false)` wrong wrong, as in break the code wrong. Or just bad practice, I just wanted to be 100% sure that it was a boolean and it was false. also where does the `.value` go?

Comment: @hollowpetal It depends. It can work or break code. `new Boolean(false) == false`, but `new Boolean(false) !== false`. It is very bad practice and you should avoid it. Why would you think that `false` isn't enough to have the boolean value `false`? If you don't trust the language, don't use the language. `false` is a keyword and cannot be altered by any code.

Comment: @Elior not sure if my exhaustion is making me blind, but I can't see anything new.

Comment: @IngoBürk I was anxious that it might save a string or the like, irrational, but this is driving me nuts.

Comment: @Elior "now in javascript you can add functionality to this button. so when you want to get this button in javaScript you can use the function `document.getElementById('order')`" is still confusing me then. Sorry I'm such a pain, I just have no idea where to apply this function. Maybe the edit isn't showing on my end ;_;. I just want to get this working so I can sleep.

Comment: @Elior so in my code would `onclick="validate()"`be acceptable or... also how do I combine it with the existing function the `onclick="calculateorder()` that my team mate did, or do I have to make the validation a part of that function?

Comment: You want to calculate when the validiation is finished and returns 'true'?

Comment: I think you can call the calculateOrder() function in the validation() function. When the user name is valid. 
and in the onclick change the calculateorder() to validate() as you want

Comment: oh... so I would make it `onclick="validate()` and at the end of the code I can make an if else along the lines of `if { b = true } then {calculateorder()}` or is it `{function.calculateorder()}` and for multiple vars would I do `if a = true` `if b = true` and so on `{calculateorder()}`

Comment: if you'll make it onclick=validate() you can call the calculateOrder() within the function validate() when the user name is valid..

Comment: @Elior I just updated the code in my op (update 2) it still seems to be throwing.. uh nothing at all ;_;

Comment: ... semi colons *facepalm*... fixed that.. there still seems to be a problem ;_;

Comment: because when you're calling to a function you don't need to 
call it like function calculateorder(); as you did in the "if" statement.
you just write calculateorder(); 
the function keyword is when you're declaring about function.

Comment: @Elior `if clientnamevalid = true;
  { 
   calculateorder();
  }` 
is still flagging ;_; thanks for helping me, I'm learning so much

Comment: it should be 

if (clientnamevalid == true) { calculateorder();}

Comment: @hollowpetal remove the semicolon from the if statement..
see in my edit2 how the if statement should be..

Comment: is it alert "client name invalid"? 
can you post the calculateOrder code?

Comment: Please move extended discussion to [chat], thanks :)